# Android application connection to db2

Tags: android, db2

IS there a way to connect to remote DB2 instance through android application development?

Comment: You may want to tag the question for the platform DB2 is running on.  Your connection details may depend on whether it is DB2 for z/OS (IBM mainframe), LUW (Linux/Unix/Windows/Solaris/etc), or IBM i (aka AS/400)

Answer (score 2):

I tried a while ago to take across the db2jcc.jar (the DB2 JDBC driver) to Android.

I discovered there were quite a lot of "standard" Java libraries missing from Dalvik that you need to run this : mostly in the security space.    Because they are in standard JVM namespaces you also can't do a conversion of the required JARs yourself.

I discovered that the same set of libraries are a problem for other enterprise DBMS JDBC drivers such as those from Oracle. on Android

So your only option is to use a three architecture of some sort.   Probably best is the previous suggestion of an app server running web services.   Whether you produce web services tailored to your application or a set of more generic "data services" is a design decision for you to look into.   Creating web services for DB2 targetted at Websphere Application Server or WAS-CE (basically Geronimo) is faily easy using IBM Data Studio (make sure you get the latest 3.1.1), where the whole process is a small number of mouse clicks over the top of a stored procedure (and producing simple SPs is also very simple within DataStudio).

HTH

Phil Nelson
ScotDB Limited

Answer (score 0):

If the db2 server is on the internet, you will have to come up with a web service to handle data transactions with your application. The app can use the APIs provided by the web service to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't done that, you should be able to do so with JDBC

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do database connectivity from your application to remote server with DB2 or any database. To do this thing you should have internet enabled for your application and you should use technologies such as JSON and with simple web scripting you can do it easily. We resently made such a application using JSP and MySql database.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way than writing a Web Service and still keeping the same level of security: use a Virtual JDBC Driver that uses a three-tier architecture: your JDBC code is sent through HTTP to a remote Servlet that filters the JDBC code (configuration & security) before passing it to the DB2 JDBC Driver. The result is sent you back through HTTP. There are some free software that use this technique. Just Google "Android JDBC Driver over HTTP".